# Close the JInternalFrame through JMenuItem

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

Hi  i am creating internal frame, i want close internalframe through menu item but it closed the total frame. please help me.

Here is my code,

```
public class CloseWindow extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    JTextArea tx;
    int i=0;
    public CloseWindow() {
        initComponents();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents() {

        tPane = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        Crete = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        close = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jMenu1.setText("File");

        Crete.setText("Create");
        Crete.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                CreteActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jMenu1.add(Crete);

        close.setText("Close");
        close.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                closeActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jMenu1.add(close);

        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(tPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 427, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(tPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents
   private void CreteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_CreteActionPerformed
        ActionEvent ae=evt;
        final JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("");
        i++;
        internalFrame.setName("Document"+i);
        internalFrame.setClosable(true);
        internalFrame.setSize(700, 700);
        tx = new JTextArea();
        internalFrame.add(tx);
        tPane.add(internalFrame);
        internalFrame.setSize(internalFrame.getMaximumSize());
        internalFrame.pack();
        internalFrame.setVisible(true);
        internalFrame.addInternalFrameListener(new InternalFrameAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void internalFrameClosing(InternalFrameEvent e) {

            tPane.remove(internalFrame);
        } 
    });


    }    



    private void closeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_closeActionPerformed
      WindowEvent tabClosingEvent = new WindowEvent(this,WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(tabClosingEvent);  
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CloseWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CloseWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CloseWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CloseWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new CloseWindow().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem Crete;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem close;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private javax.swing.JTabbedPane tPane;
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new `WindowEvent` with

```
WindowEvent tabClosingEvent = new WindowEvent(this,....
```

and posting this to the event queue. The `this` here refers to the main frame. That's why it is closed.

However, you should usually **not** mess around with the event queue manually. Instead, you should do the respective actions programmatically with the method that perform the desired actions.

There are some parts of the code between the first `{` and the last `}` that might benefit from a slight cleanup, but in order to solve the actual issue, you could change your `closeActionPerformed` method to something like this:

```
private void closeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{
    Component c = tPane.getSelectedComponent();
    if (c instanceof JInternalFrame)
    {
        JInternalFrame f = (JInternalFrame)c;
        f.dispose();
        tPane.remove(f);
    }
}
```

(BTW: Then you also don't need the `InternalFrameListener` any more)